# WiFi not working properly in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on Macbook Pro

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, macintosh

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Macbook Pro. Everything seems to work fine except the WiFi. The wireless connection is very slow and intermittent. Wired connection works like a charm however.

I tried the solution here but it didn't work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/272010/extremely-slow-and-or-unreliable-wifi-on-a-2009-macbook-pro-with-bcm4322

Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Max

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with the same issue running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Macbook Pro retina. I'm getting download speeds of 3Mb/s when I'm in Ubuntu, but 50Mb/s when I switch to OS X.

Just tried:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

And it doubled my download speed to 6Mb/s... It's not much, but after trying everything else it feels like progress.